# JQuery.css(property, value) cause 404 not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the error I am getting:

> GET http://localhost:8888/assets/gifs/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found)

This is my code:

```
$("#town-icon").css("background", "url(../../assets/gifs/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat");
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

This works when added to a css file:

```
.select .arr {
  background: url("../../assets/gifs/ajax-loader.gif") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Why is it not finding the file when applying styling dynamically vis `JQuery.css()`?

Comment: the url in the css file is relative to the css file, but when applied via js, it's relative to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your SCRIPT folder and your ASSET folder are in the same root level. Your CSS folder is deeper by one level. In order to retrieve that .gif, you must escape the root back two levels (`../../`) But since your script is one folder up and even with the assets folder removing the (`../../`) should fix your problem. If you have the script file inside another folder within the SCRIPT folder, then escape back once only (`../`)

```
$("#town-icon").css("background", "url(/assets/gifs/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat");
```